# Selecting similar videos except for current one using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, except

I have a table with videos' info and when someone selects a video on my site I have a small section that shows all other videos with similar tags. Now, I want to exclude the video that is currently selected. Here's my query:

```
SELECT video_title, video_desc
FROM videos WHERE tags LIKE 
$CurrentTags AND   
'$CurrentVideo' NOT IN
(SELECT video_id FROM videos WHERE video_id = '$CurrentVideo')
```

The query works fine (as in there are no errors) but it sometimes still returns me a video that is already selected. I think it's obvious but I'll clarify anyway

$CurrentTags is a set of tags of currently selected video on the website.

$CurrentVideo is a unique video id of currently selected video on website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be the same as your quer without a subselect:

```
SELECT video_title, video_desc
FROM videos 
WHERE (
    tags LIKE $CurrentTags
OR
    tags LIKE $otherTags
OR
    tags LIKE $otherTags
)
AND   
    video_id <> '$CurrentVideo';
```

Comment: Still returns me a video that is already selected. Really makes no sense.

Comment: show us the the executed query with the parameter. The error can be only if the $CurrentVideo is wrong

Comment: I just checked and if I write the query directly to CMD then it excludes and $CurrentVideo properly. Then I echo'ed $currentVideo on site and it's 100% correct. I think it must be some problem with $CurrentTags because in CMD I only used one tag to test whereas on the site there are multiple.

Comment: the tags are not important. the current video is the selected and with **video_id <> '$CurrentVideo'** this video is excluded from the result

Comment: This is the best example of what's happening http://i.imgur.com/47QUYa3.png On the left here are "similar videos" with similar videos and echo'ed query that is used to fetch them.

Comment: To clarify "plik" is file and it's always unique. There are NO two files with the same name.

Comment: There a things i can see. The first LIKE did not work without and % in the string or you can change it to = . the second i see that compare 'Roller' with 'Roller-2' if i understand it correct so there is no duplicate

Comment: The first LIKE is literally only here just to be able to inclue longer string that consists of repeating "OR LIKE '%tag%'" (loop creates OR LIKE for every video tag). I even made up some nonsense string so the first LIKE doesn't fetch anything.

Comment: I checked and it's DEFINETLY tags fault.  When there's only one tag matching then <> works and excludes currently selected video BUT when they are two or more tags matching then <> is hopeless and query fetches current video anyway. Why?

Comment: ahh - put () around your likes: **SELECT ... WHERE (your likes) AND video_id <> '$CurrentVideo';**

Comment: in your sample is only one like !! so there is not this problem

Comment: @Bermd Buffen Ok, I solved it. after every LIKE there has to be AND <> so if they are two tags then query must be WHERE tags LIKE '%tag1%' AND id_video <> $CurrentVideo OR tags LIKE '%tag2%' AND id_video <> $CurrentVideo

Comment: i have change it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT video_id FROM videos WHERE video_id = '$CurrentVideo')`. That subquery returns the same output as it's input.  You already have video ID; you don't need to select it again.  Have you tried just an inequality operator there?  Furthermore, you're comparing it to itself, aren't you?  Try this instead:

`video_id <>'$CurrentVideo'`